# Can't add lines to my table despite the good formatting Json (DataTables)

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I want to fill a table (DataTables) with an AJax request

My request ajax returns Json but impossible to fill the table, I have this error:

**DataTables warning: table id=dt-table - Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 1, column 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4**

**My table:**

```
<div>
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table id="dt-table" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Invoice</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**My JS:**

```
var table = $('#dt-table').DataTable({});

$(document).on("click", ".button", function() {

    var inputVal = $(this).text();
    var selectVal = $('#select option:selected').val();

    $.post("/ajax/invoice.php", {find: inputVal, column: selectVal}).done(function(data){
      console.log(data)
      table.rows.add(data).draw();
    });

});
```

**The ajax response:**

```
[{"invoice":"AZERT"},{"invoice":"JFKDH"},{"invoice":"DKHFVEP"}]
```

**My request:**

```
$column = $_POST['column'];

    $request = $bdd->prepare("SELECT invoice from table_master WHERE $column = :find");
    $request->execute(array(
      ':find' => $_POST['find']
      ));

    $result = $request->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    echo json_encode($result);
```

I do not see where the problem comes from, I look at the DataTables documentation and my json is normally properly formatted

https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows.add()

Answer (score 0):

You need to define taht you're gonna use `invoice` parameter as your column source like :

```
var table = $('#dt-table').DataTable({"columns":[{ "data": "invoice"}]});
```

Comment: Thank you but I have the same error : "DataTables warning: table id=dt-table - Requested unknown parameter 'invoice' for row 1, column 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4"

Comment: I reversed both : [{ "invoice": "data"}],  Datatables no longer displays an error **but I have one letter per line on my table**

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with php but I ran into the same issue when I was trying to update some cells on a row click from a modal popup. I ended up setting the datatable properties inside of my post callback. I also had to destroy my table prior to recreating it. Here's my LoadData function callback:

```
         .done(function (result) {
                if (result.isError) {
                    window.location.href = result.newUrl;
                }
                else {
                    var html = '';
                    $('#searchTable').dataTable().fnDestroy();
                    $('#searchTableBody').empty();

                    if (result.TransactionDetails.lenght == 0) {
                        html += '<tr><td>No Records Found</td></tr>';
                    }
                    else {

                        $.each(result.TransactionDetails, function (i, item) {

                            html += '<tr><td id="hiddenIdentifier" >' + item.x + '</td><td>' + item.y + '</td><td>' + item.z + '</td><td style="width: 10%" >' + item.a + '</td><td style="width: 30%">' + item.b + '</td><td>' + item.c + '</td><td style="width: 50%">' + item.d + '</td><td style="width: 80%"><input type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#detailsModal" class="table-btn" id="btnViewDetails" value="View Details" /><input type="button" id="btnEditAmt" data-toggle="modal" class="table-btn" data-target="#amtModal" value="Edit Amount" /></td></tr>';
                        });
                    }
                    $('#searchTableBody').append(html);

                    var table = $('#searchTable').DataTable({
                        searching: false,
                        paging: true,
                        columnDefs: [
                            {
                                "targets": [0],
                                "visible": false,
                                "searchable": false
                            },
                            {
                                "targets": [1],
                                "visible": true,
                                "searchable": true
                            },
                            {
                                "targets": [7],
                                "orderable": false
                            }
                        ]
                    })

                    $('#searchTable').show();
                    $('#loaderLoadData').fadeOut();
                }

        })
```

It only worked via the Api calls. fnDestroy() is key. Make sure you destroy it before recreating it. Also notice I set the DataTable properties inside of the done function.